# Laravel - pass database table data to js variable

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

How can I pass database rows to a javascript array, as a variable, in laravel?

I have a backoffice saving each registry on a database table, but I'm using a third-party js module that uses an array of data to import content. I need to serve my database data as an array for that specific variable.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Create an API endpoint which will response data as JSON and then catch it in your JS by doing an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP tag in javascript to use object.

e.g you send $object from controller to view.

In your script use

```
<script>    
var object = {!! json_encode($object->toArray()) !!};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the object to the view as Json then on the view

```
var object = {{ $object }};
```